# I can't insert data to my database (mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm learning now MySQL and I have a some problem. I tried to make a post request to my db::

[image]

My code from client side:

```
async function sendValues() {
    const settings = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(product)
    }
    try {
        const fetchResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:9001/products', settings);
        const data = await fetchResponse.json();
        console.log(data) // what the user send
    } catch (err) {
        return err
    }
}
```

My code from server side:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { c_id, p_name, p_price } = req.body
    const q =
        `
        INSERT INTO products (c_id,p_name,p_price)
        VALUES("${c_id}", "${p_name}" , "${p_price}")
        `;
    con.query(q, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result)
    });
});
```

Comment: First, make sure that you can establish a proper connection between client and server. Then you can execute queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible mistakes:

1.check the connection between client and server. as mentioned above.

2.check the table name, data type of attributes, name of attributes you are providing.

Answer (score 0):

The rest endpoint is `/` and you are calling `products` change your backend code as below.

```
router.post('/products', (req, res) => {
    const { c_id, p_name, p_price } = req.body
    const q =
        `
        INSERT INTO products (c_id,p_name,p_price)
        VALUES("${c_id}", "${p_name}" , "${p_price}")
        `;
    con.query(q, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(result)
    });
});
```